# Retag [Windows-2012] into [Windows-Server-2012] or [Windows-Server-2012-R2]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[windows-2012](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-2012) contains 54 questions.  All of them appear to actually be about Windows Server 2012 or Windows Server 2012 R2.

Shall we re-tag these questions?

What do to with the [windows-2012](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-2012) tag?

Comment: Sounds like a good case for creating a tag synonym to me, I don't know of any non "Server" version of 2012....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've gone ahead and merged [windows-2012](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-2012) into [windows-server-2012](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-server-2012)

```
updating post history, 55 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 54 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 53 rows affected
updating Documentation tag proposal commitments, 0 rows affected
updating DocTags, 0 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, new count: 673
tag remapping of [windows-server-2012] and [windows-2012] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
3 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym windows-2012 -> windows-server-2012 was approved!
```

Comment: [status-completed] then?